# Prometheus container connection refused

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, prometheus

I have prometheus , nginx-vts , php and nginx-vts-exporter all in separated containers i'm trying to get metrics to prometheus from the exporter ,, it keeps telling me 
    Get http://127.0.0.1:9913/metrics: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9913: connect: connection refused

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJaNa.png)

this is my prometheus.yml

global:

scrape_interval: 15s

evaluation_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:

- job_name: nginx

  static_configs:

  - targets: ['127.0.0.1:9913']

this is an error from the exporter when i run the compose file

fetchHTTP failed Get http://localhost/status/format/json: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Comment: There are different ways to wire the connection between your containers. One pretty simple way would be to use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/). Instead of `127.0.0.1` you would reference the containers by names. These would be resolved to IP addresses via DNS.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, the solution for me was to add this `--net=host` flag when running the docker of the prometheus(not push-gateway). Then everything just clicked :)

So it looked something like:

docker run 
-p 9090:9090 
--net=host 
prom/prometheus

For good measure this was what I was scraping with(Prometheus config):

- job_name: prometheus-local-discovery 
honor_timestamps: true 
scrape_interval: 30s 
scrape_timeout: 29s 
metrics_path: /metrics 
scheme: http 
honor_labels: true 
static_configs: 
- targets: 
- localhost:9091

(Please note that the .yml config file is "tab-sensitive" and I was not able to format it better in here.)

Answer (score 0):

When we run Prometheus with Node exporter or any other metrics collecting container, we have to add this in the Prometheus configuration file.

Here, while defining "targets" under "scrape_configs" mention the IP address of the host machine where node exporter is running.

Use "['localhost:9090']" for prometheus and "['host_IP:9100']" for node exporter or any other metrics collecting container.